# Multiple linear regression in R across different groups

Tags: r, lm

I have a group of 17 subjects divided into 2 different groups (2 different types of one disease). I would like to perform a multiple linear regression analysis in R across these groups with 7 covariates in total. Is there a way to perform this in R that after I get the results I could associate them with a certain group? Basically, I'm interested in evaluate if the differences in the values of PCC_MC, SMA_MC and IPS_MC are correlated with one of the several covariates. But if I have a significant result, for example, cov1 how can I identify which of the two groups are associated to that result?

[image]

Comment: (1) You can do this in any way you please in `R`, exactly as you would with any regression program: either include `groups` directly or include `factor(groups)`.  Because this is a binary variable, it makes no difference. (2) Fitting three models with eight covariates (including `groups`) with only 17 subjects guarantees you will over-fit the data.

Comment: Seventeen subjects for 7 predictors in a model is probably way too few. To get a model of any utility it is generally recommended that you have 10 to 15 cases per predictor in your model. You may want to stick to simpler measures of association (e.g., group differences, correlations etc.).